# Syntax Error: Token '&&' not a primary expression

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs

I hae the following code in my ionic app view :

```
<ion-item 
    ng-repeat="milestone in project.milestones" 
    href="#/tab/activity/{{milestone.slug}}/milestone" 
    ng-style="{{now | amDifference : null : 'days'}} > {{milestone.due_date | amDifference : null : 'days'}} && {'color':'red'} || {'color': 'blue'}">
```

However it is giving me this error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '&&' not a primary expression at column 6 of the expression [0 >  && {'color':'red'} || {'color': 'blue'}] starting at [&& {'color':'red'} || {'color': 'blue'}].

Hovever the above error doesnt seem to affect execution (for now i think) i have no idea where it is comming from.
in the code above i am trying to compare the current time to a set time using moment.js

Answer (score 4):

The expression in your ng-style attribute doesn't make sense:

```
{{now | amDifference : null : 'days'}} > {{milestone.due_date | amDifference : null : 'days'}} && {'color':'red'} || {'color': 'blue'}
```

It should be a single object literal, or an angular expression that evaluates to one.

To the left of the '>' you have something enclosed in '{{'. That's not valid in an angular expression. Only use '{{' to substitute in a place that doesn't otherwise take an angular expression'. I think you've done that because you want to use a filter on the value, but that's not going to be easy to do in a situation like this as you would have to expose the filter into the scope.

As near as I can make you are trying to do something like this:

```
$scope.itemStyle = function itemStyle(now, milestone) {
    if (amDifferenceFilter(now, null, 'days') > amDifferenceFilter(milestone.due_date, null, 'days')) {
        return { color: 'red' }
    } else {
        return { color: 'blue' }
    }
}
```

You will also need to inject `amDifferenceFilter` into your controller if you haven't already done so, or just use moment.js directly from the javascript code.

Then your html should be:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="milestone in project.milestones"
  href="#/tab/activity/{{milestone.slug}}/milestone"
  ng-style="itemStyle(now,milestone)">
```

Writing complex expressions in `ng-style` can be confusing, it is often better to pull them out into the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a " after ng-style.

Comment: While this may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post.